# Phone Number Link for devices, downgradable for Desktop?

Tags: android, iphone, tel

Ok, so it's pretty standard these days to make a phone number a link in your HTML, sure.
So on a mobile phone, someone clicks the link:

```
<a href="tel:555-555-555">555-555-555</a>
```

And sure, that's fine for phones, but what is the best way to downgrade for desktop?
From a UX/UI point of view, keeping it as a link is a bit silly on desktop.

The last thing I want to do is browser sniff with JS, and then kill the link, while keeping the number. Is there a standards compliant way to do this yet?

From a UX/UI point of view, desktop users should be able to select the text and paste it into their document/software of choice, without accidentally clicking the link.